# Delete a pointer with a pointer to that pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator, delete-operator

Well consider this:

```
int * hello = new  int[10]; 
for (register int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    *(hello + i) = i;
int * & hello_ref = hello; 
delete[] hello_ref ; 
for (register int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    cout << *(hello + i) << std::endl;
```

Now`hello_ref` can succesfully delete the memory which is allocated by `new` ... From a fact that the reference and pointer are very close how we do the same thing with pointer to pointer to new memory allocated

---

now consider this

```
int i = 0;
unsigned int * hello = new  unsigned int[6]; 
for (register int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    *(hello + i) = i; 
unsigned int * bye = new  unsigned int[4];
for (register int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    *(bye + i) = i; 
unsigned int ** del = new  unsigned int *[2];
*del = bye; 
*(del + 1) = hello; 
delete[] * del; 
delete[] * (del + 1);
```

Is there any way that we could delete the new allocated memory for hello and bye with the del pointer to pointer ... these could just clear the data which hello and bye pointed to ....

Comment: Are you using this in actual code?  It looks like you should be using a `std::vector` and then you do not have to worry about the management.

Comment: yes this is part of my code .... i'm some how begineer to c++ and i prefer to follow the my reference approach

Comment: `hello[i]` reads better than `*(hello + i)`...

Comment: that's actually right but this clearly show that it's a pointer that we are now use

Comment: i don't get the down voting

Comment: Didn't downvote, but the question is unclear. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: probably downvoted, because it is not clear at all why you want to use `new` and `delete` in the first place, when a simple `std::vector` (as pointed out by NathanOliver) would do the job.

Comment: the question i think is clear ... it's just want to delete new allocated memory with a pointer to the pointer that is new passed the address of the first element of the array to it ...

Comment: and second ... i told that im begineer and my tools is just limited to this kind of work

Comment: imho (in contradiction to many books and teachers) especially for a beginner it is easiest to avoid `new`, `delete` and c-style arrays completely. You actually dont need them unless you are doing something really complicated.

Comment: i just say that i'm begineer to c++ not to c ...

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, but the first example is undefined behavior (accessing memory after freeing it) so could potentially crash or give wrong results.

Comment: yeah i know that ...  form the stand point the close relation between a reference with a pointer i made that example that succefully clear the allocated memory ... but how we could do the same thing with pointer to that pointer to that new allocated memory (as you now new returned the address of the first allocated memory to the variable on the left of assignment)

Comment: @Parano You repeat again and again you're a beginner. But we aren't! Take advice to use `std::vector` and not to use raw pointer

Comment: If you're experienced in c, then aren't you experienced with manual management of dynamic memory? Just imagine how you would use free when you have pointer to pointer to memory from malloc. It's entirely analogous to new and delete in c++.

Comment: *"that's actually right but this clearly show that it's a pointer that we are now us"* Except you are not....

Comment: @Parano I don't see what the issue is here, really.  The rules are **very** simple -- the pointer value returned to you when you issue a `new[]` must be the very same pointer value you use when a `delete []` is issued.  There is no further explanation needed.   All the talk about references and such is a moot point.  The most important, and frankly, the only point is in my first couple of sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to delete the array referenced by `del`:

```
delete[] del;
```

You are already deleting the arrays referenced by `hello` and `bye`:

```
delete[] * del; 
delete[] * (del + 1);
```

Though this would be more idiomatic:

```
delete[] del[0];
delete[] del[1];
```

Or even better, avoid using `new` and `delete` altogether, taking advantage of modern C++ features. What you are writing looks more like C.

```
#include <array>
#include <numeric>
#include <tuple>

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
std::array<T, N> make_increasing_array(T initial = T())
{
  std::array<T, N> array;
  std::iota(array.begin(), array.end(), initial);
  return array;
}

int main()
{
  auto del = std::make_tuple(
    make_increasing_array<unsigned int, 6>(),
    make_increasing_array<unsigned int, 4>());

  auto& hello = std::get<0>(del);
  auto& bye = std::get<1>(del);
}
```

Comment: still we have the memory allocated for the hello and bye ... check that ...now their value is MAX_UNSIGNED INT but there are still exist

Comment: @Parano You cannot tell whether the memory is still allocated by inspecting the elements of the array after you have deleted the array. Maybe they'll be zero, maybe they won't. Maybe your computer will crash, or maybe your hard drive will be wiped. Accessing the elements of a deleted array is undefined behaviour. Besides, C++ is designed for efficiency; it has no reason to zero the array before deallocating the memory, so don't expect it to.

Comment: check that in the debugger  for example coutinue your program in some further lines and then set watcher or breakpoint to further lines ...

Comment: @Parano You may still be able to inspect the array in your debugger. If you're running in debug mode, the elements may be set to some default value so you can easily see that they've been deleted. Perhaps `MAX_UNSIGNED_INT` is that value.

Comment: but we don't see this behavior if for example just make an array with new and delete the allocated memory with delete ... agree with this ... ?

Comment: @Parano The behaviour will depend on your compiler. If you are running in debug mode and have called `delete` the same number of times as `new`, and didn't get an error message, you probably did the right thing.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly then the answer on the 1st part of your question will be something like this:

```
...
   int * * hello_ref = &hello;
   delete[] *hello_ref;
...
```

About second part, you did exactly what you asked. Those 2 `delete` do the job. Just add `delete[] del;` as a final touch.

Comment: that's not working .. add this to the second part and see that .... delete[] del; 
 for (register int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  cout << *(bye + i) << std::endl;

Comment: @Parano `delete` just deallocates the memory used by the array; it doesn't zero the elements of the array. What you are doing is illegal (undefined behaviour) but it won't necessarily tell you.

Comment: @Parano, you just printed out some part of memory which is ok. Using this data will lead to undefined behavior. See also previous comment from Joseph Thomson.